# Deducing an identity for iterating a lie bracket

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, lie-algebras

Show that if $a,y \in gl(V)$ are linears maps, then for any $m \geq 1$ we have:

$$ay^m = y^ma + \sum^m_{k=1} \binom{m}{k}y^{m-k}a_k$$

Where $a_1=[a,y]$ and $a_{n+1}=[a_n,y]$.

Deduce that:

$$ad(y^m)=\sum^m_{k=1} (-1)^{k+1} \binom{m}{k}y^{m-k}ad(y)^k$$

---

my attempt:

So i'm still working on the first part, that is, showing that

$$ay^m = y^ma + \sum^m_{k=1} \binom{m}{k}y^{m-k}a_k$$

I am proceeding by induction. The base case holds by the definition of the bracket. Assume that the case is true for all $k \leq m$, then we want to show:

$$ay^{m+1} = y^{m+1}a + \sum^{m+1}_{k=1} \binom{m+1}{k}y^{m+1-k}a_k$$

To this extent, we apply our induction hypothesis:

$ay^{m+1}=ay^my$

$=[y^ma + \sum^m_{k=1} \binom{m}{k}y^{m-k}a_k]y$

$= y^may + \sum^m_{k=1} \binom{m}{k}y^{m-k}a_ky$

$=y^m([a,y]+ya) + \sum^m_{k=1} \binom{m}{k}y^{m-k}a_ky$

$=y^{m+1}a+y^m[a,y] + \sum^m_{k=1} \binom{m}{k}y^{m-k}a_ky$

Okay, cool, so I just need to show that

$$y^m[a,y] + \sum^m_{k=1} \binom{m}{k}y^{m-k}a_ky = \sum^{m+1}_{k=1} \binom{m+1}{k}y^{m+1-k}a_k$$

Could somebody help me finish this? Also, deducing the second part of the question also looks quite daunting, I'm quite bad at this type of thing. Help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the notation
$$ad(y)a=[y,a],\quad l(y)a:=ya,\quad r(y)a:=ay$$
(so $ad(y)$, $r(y)$ and $l(y)$ are linear maps $gl(V)\to gl(V)$) we have
$$r(y)=l(y)-ad(y)$$
and $l(y)ad(y)=ad(y)l(y)$. As a result
$$r(y)^n= (l(y)-ad(y))^n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}l(y)^{n-k}ad(y)^k.$$
That's the first identity, and the second one is just $l(y)^n-r(y)^n$.

**edit:** forgot the binomial coefficients :/

Comment: I'm still having trouble seeing the second identity. I expanded out $l(y)^n - r(y)^n$.... So we will get to sums that differ only in the first one has a $r(y)^{n-k}$ where the second one has a $l(y)^{n-k}$... Subtracting these from eachother, I don't see how to get what we are looking for... Thank you for your time I really appreciate it

Comment: The first identity to be proved did not have an alternating summation, yet yours does.. Am I not seeing something obvious here?

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa for those signs - note that $a_n = (-1)^n ad(y)^n a$. For your 2nd identity - if in $l(y)^n-r(y)^n$ you replace $r(y)^n$ by my last equation, you'll get it.

Comment: You're such a boss!! You deserve a less generic username!!

Comment: Does $ad(y)^n = l(y)^n - r(y)^n$?? It seems not:

$ad(y)^2a = [y[ya]] = [y[ya-ay] = [y,ya] - [y,ay] = y^2a -  yay - yay + ay^2$... do'nt we get the extra terms $yay$?

Comment: no, but $ad(y^n)$ does (and that's what you wanted to compute)

Comment: ugh.. THank you for being patience with my incompetence !!